# changing APEX tag attributes from controller?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex-code

I want to know if I can change Apex VisualForce tag attributes from the controller.

**Can i do something like this?:**

tag:

```
 <apex:selectList id="Status" value="blah blah" multiselect="false" size="1">
```

in the controller:

```
if (inc.Status__c == 'Closed'){
    Status.Rendered = false
}
```

Hope that makes sense!

**I am current doing this**, which i think is a bit long winded and want to avoid:

tag

```
 <apex:selectList id="Status" value="blah blah" rendered="{!IncidentIsClosed}">
```

in the controller

```
   if (inc.Status__c == 'Closed'){
    IncidentIsClosed = false;
    }

    ....

    public Boolean getIncidentIsClosed() {
            return IncidentIsClosed;
        }
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax for merge fields (stuff in `{!...}` brackets) is same as for validation rules, formula fields, workflow triggering conditions etc. So you can use functions like `TODAY()` as well as some more complex logic.

So I think that if "inc" object is visible on your page then something like

```
...rendered="{!not(inc.Status='Closed')}
```

should do the trick. If you use standard controller then replace "inc" with sObject name (like "Case").

Answer (score 0):

I came to Visualforce from a .NET environment where you could change the page from the controller (or by that means to create parts of the page from the controller), so I understand your question...

Unfortunately, you can't do the same in Visualforce.